# Unstable framerate for JavaScript animation using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

For personal education I am trying to build a Pong implementation in JavaScript / HTML.

I have been reading up on [rendering performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/), but when I apply the theory in practice, it seems to fall short.

[image: Fluctuating performance]

From my understanding, requestAnimationFrame should provide me with fluid stable 60 fps animation, given my logic and subsequent rendering can be completed within a 16 ms timeframe. In this case, each iteration takes between 1 - 2 ms and yet, I see my framerate jumps between 45 fps and 75 fps, occasionally producing "long frames".

I am running Chrome on OS X 10.12 on a Mac Mini (Late 2012).

I have tried using a canvas, I have tried a CSS animate approach and I have tried a top/left approach. I have tried Safari and I have tried incognito. However, the jank remains.

What am I missing?

For reference, here is my script (in CoffeeScript):

```
class window.PongGame

  @launch: ->
    window.pong = new PongGame()
    pong.start()

  constructor: ->
    @ball_size = 32
    @width = 640
    @height = 480
    @y = @height / 2
    @x = 0
    @yVel = 3
    @xVel = 3
    @ball = document.getElementById("pong_ball")

  start: ->
    requestAnimationFrame => @new_frame()

  new_frame: ->
    @handle_collisions()
    @move_ball()
    @animate()
    requestAnimationFrame => @new_frame()

  handle_collisions: ->
    if (0 <= @x <= @width - @ball_size) is false
      @xVel = -@xVel

    if (0 < @y < @height - @ball_size) is false
      @yVel = -@yVel

  move_ball: ->
    @x += @xVel
    @y += @yVel

  animate: ->
    @ball.setAttribute("style", "transform: translate(#{@x}px, #{@y}px); width: #{@ball_size}px; height: #{@ball_size}px")
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nielsbuus/ptLk3ma0/2/

### Update

I have tested my code on an older MacBook Pro (2011) and the framerate is almost stable - a lot closer to 60 fps fixed than my Mac Mini.

Answer (score 1):

There are several fun facts to keep in mind, with regard to `requestAnimationFrame` performance in browsers...

1. Using the profiler affects the results. I'm working on a three.js based WebGL project where the integrated FPS counter reports a relatively steady 60fps. But, if I activate Chrome's timeline tool and measure my frame rendering times, the timeline shows the app dropping 4-6 frames per second, even when there is no code in the render loop at all.
2. The browser manages lots of other activities, and they can affect animation performance. Running my app in a long lived Firefox instance with lots of memory in use always gets worse performance than running it in a fresh instance. Streaming video in another tab in Chrome cuts the framerate for my app in another down to 30 FPS (probably because they are both contending for GPU time). Garbage collection can eat tons of time out of a frame budget, minimizing object allocations and GC is an important concern for complex apps with lots of animation.
3. In particular, when using Chrome's timeline tool as you are, be sure to enable JS Profiling, and expand the GPU activity band. Your code is probably well within the 16.6ms frame budget, but on my system a dropped frame is usually associated with heavy GPU activity.

My advice? Don't take the profiler's results as absolute or representative of real world performance, and make peace with browser animation performance being a bit of a roller coaster :).

You might also consider using the [FPS counter](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js) developed for three.js (but usable anywhere I believe), which I presume has less of a distorting impact than the heavyweight profiling tools in modern browsers. Keeping it running in development can alert you to serious performance problems as you run into them.